# Swift: UIpickerView returning numbers on UIlabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uipickerview

I have 3 components in my UIpickerView and I want to return all 3 numbers that are shown on the UIpickerView but it only returns the last number that's been selected. in other words the UIlabel only shows one digit. here's what I have so far

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

let numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return numbers[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return numbers.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    label.text = numbers[row]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check :

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let val1 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)]
    let val2 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]
    let val3 = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)]

    label.text = "\(val1) \(val2) \(val3)"
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this code will likely crash because `selectedRow(inComponent:)` can return a value of -1.

Answer (score 0):

The `UILabel` only shows one digit because you're only telling it to show the most-recently selected number. Instead you need to ask `UIPickerView` what the selected index is for each component. Something like

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    label.text = (0..<3).map({ "\(pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: $0))" }).joined()
}
```

Comment: I did, but "Ambiguous reference to member '..<' " failes the app.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to convert the numbers to strings. I've updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Because the picker view contains more than one component, implementing `label.text = numbers[row]` in the `didSelectRow` delegate method won't be enough, that leads to -as you mentioned in your question- to read *only* the value of the *first* component.

To make it more clear, if you tried to change `label.text = numbers[row]` to `label.text = numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)]` you should notice that the label text would be the *second* value of the picker view, since [selectedRow(inComponent:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview/1614369-selectedrow) - `component` parameter is:

> **A zero-indexed number** identifying a component of the picker view.

Roughly speaking, if you want to get values from all components, you have to determine which component to be read, which in your case the three components.

I think the simplest *static* way to do it is:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    label.text = "\(numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)])\(numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)])\(numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)])"
}
```

But for sure, something like this -using [Higher-order functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function)- would be much preferred (mainly, same logic of [@Kevin Ballard's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46126222/5501940), with a pretty simple improvement):

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {        
    label.text = (0...2).map { "\(numbers[pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: $0)])" }.joined()
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this code will likely crash because `selectedRow(inComponent:)` can return a value of -1.